# Angular 2 : Sending Email using Mailgun in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, mailgun

I am trying to implement email notification to my app using Mailgun in Angular 2. But I'm getting console error when I execute the `send()` function. I don't know how to solve it, hope you can help me thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";

import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-confirmorder',
  templateUrl: 'confirmorder.html',
})
export class ConfirmorderPage {

  recipient: string = "sampleemail@gmail.com";
  subject: string = "FirstTesting";
  message: string = "Hello, this is just a drill.";
  mailgunUrl: string = "<--My Domain-->";
  apiKey: string = "<--My API Key-->";

    tabBarElement: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ConfirmorderPage');
  }

  send() {
        if(this.recipient && this.subject && this.message) {
            let headers = new Headers(
                {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + this.apiKey
                }
            );
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            let body = "from=email@sample.com&to=" + this.recipient + "&subject=" + this.subject + "&text=" + this.message;
            this.http.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + this.mailgunUrl + "/messages", body, options)
                .map(result => result.json())
                .do(result => console.log("RESULT: ", JSON.stringify(result)))
                .subscribe(result => {
                    console.log("SENT!");
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
                    this.recipient = "";
                    this.subject = "";
                    this.message = "";
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<--My Domain-->/messages. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a **chrome** feature that prevents cross domain requests unless the server allows it.

In this particular case the server doesn't accept the Authorization header.

If you are doing this from your backend and not chrome this should work fine.

Do this from your backend and not angular.

Also you shouldn't put your api key/secret on the client because they become public.

Comment: thank you, how exactly I needed to do to fix this error? I don't get it. I am new to Ionic and its my first time to encounter this type of problem. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Don't do this in ionic, do this on your server.

Comment: in nodejs do you mean?

Comment: If you are using nodejs then yes